# WxPython dynamically added sizers mis-behaving

Tags: python, wxpython, positioning

I'm trying to set-up a display to show the gamertag and avatar of users added to a text file, it most of the way there but I can't get them to position properly.

A quick mock-up of what I want: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xccT.png).

Here is what I currently have on start: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7et.jpg)

EDIT: I've switched from using a BoxSizer to using a GridSizer and that seems to have fixed the position issue, they no longer overlap, the shifting problem is still present however.

<strike>The sizer containing the users shouldn't be overlapping with the input sizer at the top, I don't know what is causing this.</strike>

And what happens when it updates to check for new users: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQNgH.jpg)

Might not be that easy to see but in the second image the lowest user is shifted down, it gets further and further down as the program runs, each time it is moved down by it's own height.

The relevant code areas:

- Creating the starting sizers

  ```
  self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
  self.widget_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
  #Holds input for gamertags and addition
  self.input_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

  #Content to be added immediately.
  self.gamer_tag_textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)
  self.gamer_tag_textbox.SetFocus()
  self.add_gamer_tag = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Add Friend')
  #Contains the displayed content
  self.user_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

  #Add objects to sizers
  self.input_sizer.Add(self.gamer_tag_textbox, 0)
  self.input_sizer.Add(self.add_gamer_tag, 0)

  #Set up the sizers
  self.widget_sizer.Add(self.input_sizer, 0)
  self.widget_sizer.Add(self.user_sizer, 0)
  self.main_sizer.Add(self.widget_sizer, 0)
  self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
  ```
- Adding sizers created for each user to the main user_sizer.

  ```
  def display_user_content(self, details):
      self.user_sizer.Clear(True)
      #This is different to the original code, it originally used boxsizers in the for each loop.
      self.single_user_sizer = wx.GridSizer(cols=2)
      for each in details:
          #Create sizer to contain user information
          #Get username
          username = each[0]
          #Get location of image file
          location = each[-1]
          #Create static text to contain username
          stat = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'username')
          #Load image from location and convert to bitmap.
          png = wx.Image(location, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
          #Create bitmap
          avatar = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png)
          #Add to sizer
          self.single_user_sizer.Add(avatar, 1)
          self.single_user_sizer.Add(stat, 1)
      #Add each users sizer to main user sizer
      self.user_sizer.Add(self.single_user_sizer, 1)
      #Add main user sizer to widget sizer
      self.widget_sizer.Add(self.user_sizer, 0)
      self.frame.Fit()
  ```

Full code (minus classes): [here](http://pastebin.com/k8mfEHrS)

Comment: It is very hard to understand the code especially when I cannot run it. Sure, someone may be able to see the problem off hand. But generally it is recommended to create a minimal working example which demonstrates the problem (and only the problem). For layout problems it would be good if you can create example for just the layout with colored panels or something (similar to your "quick mock-up"). Then it would be much easier to help. Also see wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Comment: BTW: It seems that you are looking for a sizer which handles a grid with rows / columns of different sizes. Consider using `wx.GridBagSizer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the display_user_content function I was adding the user_sizer to the widget_sizer each time, this was unnecessary and was causing a doubling of the number of results, I have removed that line and my code now works.

The fixed code:

```
def display_user_content(self, details):
    self.user_sizer.Clear(True)
    self.single_user_sizer = wx.GridSizer(cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=5)
    for each in details:
        #Get username
        self.username_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        username = each[0]
        #Get location of image file
        location = each[-1]
        #Create static text to contain username
        stat = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'username')
        #Load image from location and convert to bitmap.
        png = wx.Image(location, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        #Create bitmap
        avatar = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png)
        #Add to sizer
        self.single_user_sizer.Add(avatar, 0)
        self.username_sizer.Add(stat, 0)
        self.single_user_sizer.Add(self.username_sizer, 0)
    #Add each users sizer to main user sizer
    self.user_sizer.Add(self.single_user_sizer, 0)
    #Add main user sizer to widget sizer
    #self.widget_sizer.Add(self.user_sizer, 0)
    self.Fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is similar to what you would like to achieve?

```
import wx

NUMBER = 3

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=5, hgap=5)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(0, 0))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel)

        self.sizer.Add(self.text, (0, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, (0, 1))

        self.icons = []
        self.stats = []
        for i in range(NUMBER):
            icon = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(50, 50))
            icon.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
            stat = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(200, -1))
            stat.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
            self.sizer.Add(icon, (i+1, 0))
            self.sizer.Add(stat, (i+1, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
            self.icons.append(icon)
            self.stats.append(stat)

        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)  
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)   
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win1 = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Or maybe more like this?

```
import wx

NUMBER = 3

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=5, hgap=5)
        self.toolbar_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel)

        self.toolbar_sizer.Add(self.text, 0, flag=wx.CENTER)
        self.toolbar_sizer.Add(self.button, 0)
        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar_sizer, (0, 0), span=(1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.icons = []
        self.stats = []
        for i in range(NUMBER):
            icon = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(50, 50))
            icon.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
            stat = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(200, -1))
            stat.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
            self.sizer.Add(icon, (i+1, 0))
            self.sizer.Add(stat, (i+1, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
            self.icons.append(icon)
            self.stats.append(stat)

        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)  
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)   
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```